# Optimizing nested for loop statement with a class objects

Tags: python

i am a beginner python student (also beginner on stackoverflow so please excuse my lack of knowledge on formatting). I'm well versed with C, C++, java, Delphi, VB and other languages.

i am trying to loop through a list of class objects and perform some calculations. I am working with a list of about 60,000 to 100K records. In any of the mentioned languages, the following code would execute in seconds to minutes (depending on the language). But for python it is taking hours. My presumption is that the issue is with the implementation and not the language itself.

Any assistance on how i can optimize this routine would be greatly appreciated.FYI - I did searches for while loop/for loop comparisons... optimization... the examples i found seemed to simplistic and i am not familiar enough with python's method/libraries to incorporate.

```
class structure:
Stock
{ 
#mu - is float
#sigma - is a float
}
```

mylist is a list of Stock class objects (note:there are more properties in stock class than listed and only the relevant part of the function is listed to minimize confusion). The code should loop through a list of objects, perform some calculations and generate a list of the results

Code (Python 3.x):

```
for x in range(nCount):                 
nSum= 0.0
for aitem in mylist
    tp = []                
    for z in range (nInterval):                     
        a = (norm.ppf (random(), loc = aitem.mu, scale = aitem.sigma))
            a = math.exp (a)
            a = a * tp [-1]
            tp.append( a )
     aitem.price.append(np.mean(tp) )                                                 
     aitem.current = aitem.price[-1]/aitem.price[-2]         
     nSum = nSum + aitem.current* aitem.Weight                 

     RList.append(RSum)
```

Comment: This is not clear to me - is the code you wrote WORKING, but you simply want it to execute faster?  If so, please state that in the question.  If not then please clarify more clearly so we can help you.  Please see the following link to learn how to illustrate the specific problem you're having in a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). For more
information, please see [ask] and take the [tour].

Comment: What are `norm.ppf()` and `aitem`?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow :) If you already have a working code and you are looking to improve its performance, your question might be better suited for [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) stackexchange. Take a look at their [help](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help) pages for more info. Stack Overflow is more for codes that are not yet working, and you'll have provide a _specific_ problem that needs to be solved.

Comment: Hi - thanks for the response. yes. the code is working. It is just running very slow. for 60,000 records - it takes 1.5 hours... if i write the same code in C# or delphi it takes a few seconds... so i presume it is my design... i did some searches and found that it had to do with the for loop... just not sure how to optimize it.

Comment: norm is from from scipy.stats library. aitem is an object of my class. I'll check out the Code Review site if that is the better place for this. thanks